# Pre-installed ios app will have updates too after app released?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, app-store

Some users already have pre-installed app (installed manually, not from apple store).

If app will be released, will this users have new updates too?

Comment: User will not get update notification for the application. Although, on visiting application page in App Store user will get update button for the application as some application with same bundle ID already exist in the device. And updating the application through this way, they'll be able to get update notification from next onwards.

Answer (score 0):

No, only apps distributed via Testflight will be automatically updated. Ad-hoc or enterprise signed apps will not be automatically updated if an app with the same bundle id is in the app store.